# when $cl_{\tau} (A^c) = A^c$?

Tags: general-topology

A subset ‎‎$‎S‎$‎ of ‎$ ‎(X, ‎\tau)‎ $‎ is said to ‎be‎ ‎ preopen  ‎if ‎$‎ S ‎\subset‎ int‎_{‎\tau‎}‎ (cl‎_{‎\tau‎}‎ (S)‎)‎$‎‎.‎‎‎
‎The family of ‎all   ‎preopen ‎subsets of $ ‎(X, ‎\tau) ‎$‎ is denoted by $ ‎PO‎(X, ‎\tau)‎$‎.‎
‎The complement of a  ‎preopen ‎‎set in ‎$ ‎(X, ‎\tau) ‎$‎ is called ‎preclosed.

> let $A \subset X$ be both preopen and preclosed subset in $ ‎(X, ‎\tau) ‎$‎. Is $cl_{\tau} (A^c) = A^c$?

> Do space $X$ or $A$ require a specific condition to $cl_{\tau} (A^c) = A^c$?

Comment: The simple answer: the property holds iff $A$ is open.

Answer (score 2):

No to the first question, take $A=\Bbb Q$ in the reals (standard top.) Then $A$ is pre-open and pre-closed,but the closure of $A^\complement$ is $\Bbb R$, not $A^\complement$.

Comment: @Adrina The reals *are* regular, so no. Do you mean *extremally* disconnected? I don't know...

Comment: @Adrina iff $A$ is closed of course.

Comment: $\operatorname{cl}_\tau(A) = A$ iff $A$ is closed, right? @Adrina